# hola estoy desarrollando un proyecto en xamarin de una app (android) para la facultad y estoy teniendo problemas al conectar a la base de datos

Tags: mysql, c#, base-de-datos, xampp, xamarin

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using MySqlConnector;

namespace inscripcion
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public MySqlConnection DatabaseConnection { get; private set; }
        public UserInfo UserInfo { get; private set; }

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Initialize the database connection
            string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=bdises;Uid=admin;Pwd=admin;";
            DatabaseConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

            // Create a new UserInfo object with default values
            UserInfo = new UserInfo();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        }
```

El error que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
MySqlConnector.MySqlException: 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'
```

Ya me asegure lo siguiente:
De que el servidor MySQL esté en ejecución.
Que la ca configuración del servidor MySQL sea la correcta
Desactive el firewall

Comment: Lo estás haciendo mal. Esto es lo que deberías realizar: (Cliente) Aplicativo móvil -> (Servidor) Web API -> Base de datos. ¿Has llevado clases de redes de computadoras o todavía? Dependiendo de lo que respondas, te guio para que tengas un mejor fundamento de los motivos.

Answer (score 0):

Es bastante posible que tu aplicación no se pueda conectar a localhost. Ten en cuenta que tu aplicación en Xamarin se está ejecutando sobre un emulador que se considera una máquina diferente.

Hace mucho que no trabajo con Android, pero creo recordar que existía una "dirección mágica" apuntando a tu ordenador. Prueba con 10.0.2.2.

Puedes consultar esta documentación para la configuración de redes en el emulador https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking?hl=es-419